# How to validate iframe in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, validation, iframe

How can I validate iframe pattern while adding iframe, suppose I have below iframe

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/_PbGQf0x1eU?start=120" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and if  I change its pattern then it should show some error message.
So is there any way to validate this pattern.

Iframe can be contain viemo vidoe as well like

```
 <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/80825843?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Please your help would highly apprenticed.
Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by ` if change its pattern` ?

Comment: suppose I enter like anything in iframe field `dfadfadfd` then it should show error

Comment: @PrabhatMishra I have updated my question and uploaded a pic where if I enter something wrong in video field then it showing error message, same thing I want to do with iframe

Comment: so basically you want to validate the `url` entered by the user ?

Comment: @PrabhatMishra, yes  I am able to do it with video link but  not with iframe,
and admin will insert full iframe like as I given above

Comment: `<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/80825843?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
`

Comment: @PrabhatMishra are you there?

Comment: ok ,I would suggest ,just take the video url and keep `iframe` as a template and place the `user inputed video url` into that `template` or else if you want to proceed with this then better write a regex which will do the job of `validating` the whole `iframe` syntax.

Comment: @PrabhatMishra yes I was trying to write regex syntx but it is not wokring

Comment: Can you suggest me

Comment: I am trying with it
https://www.regextester.com/97597